# Select and sort integers/strings from a text file in Python

Tags: python, sorting, text, int, alphabetical

I have the following text file (Results.txt) that is currently set up like this:

```
Sophie
3
6
9
Laura
8
5
15
Alan
10
4
6
```

I am trying to select and sort this data in different ways. So far my code looks like this:

```
file = open('Results.txt', 'r')
lines = file.read().splitlines()
a = int(lines[1])
b = int(lines[2])
c = int(lines[3])
d = int(lines[5])
e = int(lines[6])
f = int(lines[7])
g = int(lines[9])
h = int(lines[10])
i = int(lines[11])
name1=lines[0]
name2=lines[4]
name3=lines[8]
allnames=[name1, name2, name3]
allnames.sort()
student1 = [a,b,c]
student2 = [d,e,f]
student3 = [g,h,i]
s1high=max(student1)
s2high=max(student2)
s3high=max(student3)

file.close()
```

I would like my program to be able to:

- Sort the test results alphabetically and show the students highest score.
- Sort by the average score, highest to lowest.
- Sort by the highest score, highest to lowest.

...and output this to the screen

As you can see I've started to import the results from the text file and convert them to integers, but surely there must be some quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you want

For reading the content from the file you can use

```
s = {lines[i]:[float(k) for k in lines[i+1:i+4]] for i in range(0,len(lines),4)}
```

This gives a dictionary of students vs marks something like this

```
s = {'Laura': [8, 5, 15], 'Sophie': [3, 6, 9], 'Alan': [10, 4, 6]}
```

For sorting according to alphabets you can use

```
for i in sorted(s.keys()):
    print i,max(s[i])
```

similarly for sorting according to average

```
# function which returns avg mark given the name  
avg_mark = lambda name:sum(s[name])/len(s[name])
for i in sorted(s.keys(),key=avg_mark,reverse=True):
    print i,avg_mark(i)
```

similarly for sorting according to highest marks

```
# function which returns highest mark given the name
high_mark = lambda name:max(s[name])  
for i in sorted(s.keys(),key=high_mark,reverse=True):
    print i,high_mark(i)
```

Hope this will help you. Feel free to comment if you need explanation for anything

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried adding the dict code and the sorting according to alphabets code, but still my program doesn't output anything. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No errors, it complies just fine. Just no outputted data!

Comment: Try printing s after the dict line, see if you are running the same file which you have edited, check if you have saved the file after editing....

Comment: Working brilliantly. Thank you so much. I would be grateful if you could help me even further and explain how the dictionary is compiled? How do the conditions determine between text and integers?

Comment: To know more about the syntax read about list comprehensions https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. The logic behind the parsing is that it takes 0th, 4th,... lines as keys and [1,2,3],[5,6,7],.... lines are items of the list

Comment: Thank you for your help. You're perhaps the most helpful guy on the web!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you meant by saying "...and show the students highest score Sort by the average score, highest to lowest Sort by the highest score, highest to lowest..."

Maybe this little code will get you started on what you wish to do.

```
file = open('Results.txt', 'r')
lines = file.read().splitlines()
my_dict = {}
key = None

# creating a dict with your data
for line in lines:
    if line.isalpha():
        key = line
        my_dict[key] = []
    else:
        my_dict[key].append(int(line))

# printing your data 
# iterating on sorted by key dict
for student in sorted(my_dict):
    print(student)
    # iterating the sorted list
    for score in sorted(my_dict[student], reverse=True):
        print(score)
```

Comment: The numbers in the text file relate to a score on a students' test results. There are three per student.

Comment: I understand that the first for loop determines between text and integers and adds them to the dict accordingly, but what about the second one? I cant figure out how the program determines what is a student and what is a score?

Comment: I added some comments to the code. the first for loop (in the second part) sorts the students names (keys). the second for loop sorts the list of grades, descending, of each student

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?  Runs on CPython 2.[67], CPython 3.[01234], Pypy 2.4.0, Pypy3 2.3.1 and Jython 2.7b3:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python

# pylint: disable=superfluous-parens
# superfluous-parens: Parentheses are good for clarity and portability

'''Get student grades'''

# port pprint
import decimal
import collections


def main():
    '''Main function'''
    students = collections.defaultdict(list)
    with open('input', 'r') as file_:
        for line in file_:
            line_sans_newline = line.rstrip('\n')
            if line_sans_newline.isalpha():
                name = line_sans_newline
            else:
                students[name].append(decimal.Decimal(line))
    names = list(students)
    names.sort()
    for name in names:
        max_grade = max(students[name])
        print('{0} {1}'.format(name, max_grade))

main()
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
val=[]
keys=[]
i=0
l=[]
lines=open('Result.txt','r').readlines()
for line in lines:
  try:
    val.append(int(line))
  except:
    keys.append(line)

for i in range(0,len(val),3):
 h=val[i:i+3]
 h.sort()
 l.append(h[::-1])
print 'Sort the test results alphabetically and show the students highest score.\n'
for i,j in zip(keys,l):
    print i,j

print 'Sort by the average score, highest to lowest.'
avlist=[float(sum(i))/len(i) for i in l ]
print avlist
while(len(avlist)):
    for i,j in zip(keys,avlist):
        if j==max(avlist):
          print i,j
          avlist.remove(j)

print '\nSort by the highest score, highest to lowest.\n'
hlist=[max(i) for i in l ]
hlist.sort()
hlist=hlist[::-1]
for k in hlist:
    for i,j in zip(keys,l):
        if max(j)==k:
            print i,j
```

Result:

```
Sort the test results alphabetically and show the students highest score.

Sophie
[9, 6, 3]
Laura
[15, 8, 5]
Alan
[10, 6, 4]

Sort by the average score, highest to lowest.

[6.0, 9.333333333333334, 6.666666666666667]
Laura
9.33333333333
Alan
6.66666666667
Sophie
6.0

Sort by the highest score, highest to lowest.

Laura
[15,8,5]
Alan
[10,6,4]
Sophie
[9,6,3]
```